# How to display different text to a user than the actual string in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a mysql database table with time stamp data stored like this:

```
User    |    Timeslot
----------------------
Paul          t1115
Aaron         t1130
Nick          t1115
```

I want to be able to reference the information as is, but have the user view the information as full timestamps (i.e. t1115 = "11:15am", t1130 = "11:30am", etc.). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? What will be value of Timeslot for time 06:00pm?

Comment: Im still new to C# so at this point I have a lot of items referencing data in the mysql server. I'm simply looking for knowledge at this point not code per say

Comment: and what do you use? WinForms? WebForms? MVC? What about 06:00pm?

Comment: program is a windows application, using visual basic, and using mysql workbench

Comment: the issue arises when I try to update the table in mysql, it's like it wont allow the ":" to be in the table. 6:00pm would be t600

Comment: ^ updated last one sorry missread ur statement

Comment: @MegaTron Maybe you should try wording your question differently. Like "What will the data be for single-digit hours?"

Comment: t600 = 6:00 pm ok. then 6:00am = ?

Comment: If this is for visual basic why is it tagged as c#? Silly question -- why are you storing timestamps like that?

Comment: I understand what youre saying. The thing is, I have pre-populated choices and those aren't options, although I could reformat them to keep it simple. would there be a way to store them as 1 string, but show the user another string?

Comment: and sorry i meant visual studios not basic

Comment: @Paul I asked you:  
t600 = 6:00 pm ok. then 6:00am = ? Did you read the comment?

Comment: I'm just gonna change it so t600 = 6am and t1800 =6pm. It makes more sense that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following should work...

```
 string input = "t1326".Replace("t", "").PadLeft(4, '0');

 string pattern = "HHmm";
 DateTime dt;

 DateTime.TryParseExact(input, pattern, null, 
     DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
 Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("h:mm tt")); //outputs 1:26 PM

 string reverse = String.Format("t{0}",dt.ToString("HHmm"));
 Console.WriteLine(reverse); //outputs t1326
```

Comment: What about am/pm? (i.e. t1115 = "11:15am", t1130 = "11:30am", etc.). And try to use time: t600, t700, t800, ...

Comment: I get an error that "DateTimeStyles" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted. This is only good up to "t1200", every number greater than that is set to "12:00 AM" - try "t2226"

Comment: @Paul you need to import `System.Globalization` - you could've hovered over the error and saw the suggestion in visual studio.

Comment: sorry, like i said im new.

Comment: Sorry. Had a typo in the date formatting. I've fixed the sample ...

Comment: It still doesn't work for t600, t700, t800

Comment: @Megatron overread the question, added this as well.

Comment: This now works after the edits, removing downvote.

Comment: "t1200" and "t0000" is pm or am in your case? It returns me 12:0

Comment: t1200 results in 12:00 PM and t0000 results in 12:00 AM (there was an `m`missing in the format string)

Comment: Thanks again guys I apologize for the confusion. I'm just super new to this. U guys were super helpful though!